# Interesting thought experiment on evaporation and pressure

Tags: evaporation

Little background: the enthalpy of vaporization equals energy required to change state, plus the work done against ambient pressure.

Say I made a balloon with Gore tex.(Gore tex is a fabric that water cannot move through but water vapor can) Gore tex is completely filled with water. Then, physical pressure is applied to the Gore tex. Would this increase the enthalphy of vaporization?

YES: because the water is under pressure from the waterproof Gore tex

No: because the air pressure is the same as the Gore tex is air permeable.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that Gore-tex isn't actually fully waterproof, as it's basically just a bunch of PTFE 'wool.' It simply looks like it's pretty hard for water to pass, not impossible. Given that 'waterproof' in the language of capitalism simply means 'one study said it stopped 75% of rain,' I'd be hesitant to apply the properties to such an... impressive... situation.

Comment: That being said, as this is a _thought experiment_, you could simply say that it's a perfect gore-tex-_like_ substance with the needed properties.

Comment: A pressure gradient induced between a liquid and a vapour. Similar situation to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomizer_nozzle

Comment: I must say, in advance, that I am not remotely good at physics. I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: squeezing the bag increases the enthalpy of vaporization but by only a minuscule amount, broadly  because pressurizing condensed matter adds little energy relative to boiling it.**

**Qualitative reasoning:**
If the pressure on the water increases but the pressure in the atmosphere stays constant, then the liquid water will be in a relatively high-energy state (equivalently, the chemical potential will rise). Therefore, the boiling temperature will decrease because evaporation is favored.

If the boiling temperature decreases, then more energy is needed to evaporate a water molecule because less kinetic energy is available. Therefore, the latent heat will increase, but not because the process of evaporation is doing any additional work on the environment relative to the unpressurized case.

Let's try to get more quantitative to potentially compare the magnitudes of changes under various conditions.

**Quantitative reasoning:** At the boiling point, the chemical potentials $\mu_\mathrm{L}$ and $\mu_\mathrm{G}$ of the liquid and the gas, respectively, are equal. We can always write $\mu_i=\mu_{i,0}+RT\ln a_i$ for component $i$, where $a$ is the activity (1 for the condensed state and percentage of the saturation pressure for the gas state). For unconfined water (i.e., no balloon), we have at the boiling point $$\mu_\mathrm{L}=\mu_\mathrm{G}$$ $$\mu_\mathrm{L,0}+RT\ln 1=\mu_\mathrm{G,0}+RT \ln 1$$ $$\mu_\mathrm{L,0}=\mu_\mathrm{G,0}$$ $$U_\mathrm{L,0}+P_\mathrm{sat}V_\mathrm{L,0}-T_\mathrm{sat}S_\mathrm{L,0}=U_\mathrm{G,0}+P_\mathrm{sat}V_\mathrm{G,0}-T_\mathrm{sat}S_\mathrm{G,0}$$ $$\Delta S=\frac{\Delta U+P_\mathrm{sat}\Delta V}{T_\mathrm{sat}}$$ because the chemical potential is simply the molar Gibbs free energy $G=H-TS=U+PV-TS$ at constant temperature and pressure, which are the conditions of a phase change. Note that I'll use $T_\mathrm{sat}$ subscript for the non-balloon case only (the boiling of free water at 1 atm) as our reference.

If we now assume a balloon and apply a gauge pressure of $p$ to the internal water, than at the equilibrium boiling point, we have $$\mu_\mathrm{L}=\mu_\mathrm{G}$$ $$\mu_\mathrm{L,0}+RT\ln 1=\mu_\mathrm{G,0}+RT \ln 1$$ $$U_\mathrm{L,0}+(P_\mathrm{sat}+p)V_\mathrm{L,0}-TS_\mathrm{L,0}=U_\mathrm{G,0}+P_\mathrm{sat}V_\mathrm{G,0}-TS_\mathrm{G,0}$$
$$pV_\mathrm{L,0}=\Delta U+P_\mathrm{sat}\Delta V-T\Delta S=(\Delta U+P_\mathrm{sat}\Delta V)\left(1-\frac{T}{T_\mathrm{sat}}\right)$$ $$T=T_\mathrm{sat}\left(1-\frac{pV_\mathrm{L,0}}{\Delta U+P_\mathrm{sat}\Delta V}\right)=T_\mathrm{sat}\left(1-\frac{pV_\mathrm{L,0}}{\Delta H_\mathrm{sat}}\right)$$ which gives the new boiling temperature, less than $T_\mathrm{sat}$, under the hand-wavey assumption that $\Delta H$ doesn't change *much* when we pressurize the bag.

Plugging in some numbers: Since $\Delta H_\mathrm{sat}\approx 41\,\mathrm{kJ/mol}$ (of which the internal energy change makes up about 95% and the $PV$ work makes up about 5%), then a gauge pressure of 1 atm on the bag (filled with water at a molar volume of 18 cc) would be expected to decrease the boiling temperature by approximately only 40 parts in a million!

As noted, the latent heat of vaporization increases with decreasing boiling temperature. A widely used fit to the relationship is the Watson equation, $$\Delta H=\Delta H_\mathrm{sat}\left(\frac{T_\mathrm{crit}-T}{T_\mathrm{crit}-T_\mathrm{sat}}\right)^{0.38}$$ where $T_\mathrm{crit}$ is the critical temperature of about 650 K.

The decrease in temperature by 50 parts in a million increases the enthalpy by only about 60 parts in a *billion*! These shifts are truly tiny for any pressure you could hope to apply manually.

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds too dumb, but isn't the latent heat Hvap = Uvap + p*V?

Comment: 2,257,000J + 101,000Pa(kg/ms2)*(1.7-0.001)m3 = 2,428,700J

Comment: Yes, $\Delta H_\mathrm{vap}=\Delta U_\mathrm{vap}+P\Delta V$. In your quantitative comment, you seem to be adding $P\Delta V$ to the latent heat, which already incorporates this term.

Comment: That is too bad. I was hoping I can improve my portable evaporation cooler :(